# Apache ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE without any data in the log

Tags: php, apache, symfony

i have a website and when the user fills a form, the response code is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

The problem is there is no information in the Apache logs.

The project is done with Symfony2 over Apache on Linux.

I don't know if there is a problem with APC,but it is difficult to track if there is no errors in the log.

Any ideas?

Comment: This happens when a server accepts a request and closes the connection with a null response. So, how does your form look like?

Answer (score 1):

This means your server has accepted the connection (your client successfully sent it), but is not sending any response back to the client

In most symfony 2 configuration, errors are intercepted and logged into the application's own log, you can try checking them in `app/logs/`

Another thing to try is to enable symfony's debug mode and then look for the request in the profiler (use "search" at the bottom right to see the list of all the latest request) and see the internal log event to try and find where the issue might be.